# Visibility to Reacticve UI

Tags: mvvm, reactive-programming, prism, reactiveui

in xaml i have something like this with Prism.

```
<Grid>
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Greeting, Mode=OneWay}" Visibility="{Binding GreetingVisibility}"/>
</Grid>
```

and ViewModel like this.

```
private string _name;
public string Name{
                      get=>_name;
                      set{
                            SetProperty(ref _name, value);
                            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Greeting));
                            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(GreetingVisibility));
                          }
                   }
public string Greeting{
                      get=> "Hello " + _name;
                      }
public Visibility GreetingVisibility=>string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)?Visibility.Collapsed:Visibility.Visible;
```

How can i make something similar with ReactiveUI, please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [WhenAnyValue](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/when-any/#variants-of-whenany) and [ObservableAsPropertyHelper](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/observable-as-property-helper).

You can set the property helper to handle the visibility and just bind to the view.  Whenever the name changes this observable will tick and just update.

something like the following

```
ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> _greetingVisibility;

_greetingVisibility =
    this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Name)
        .Select(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
        .StartsWith(false)
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .ToProperty(this, nameof(GreetingVisibility));

public bool GreetingVisibility => _greetingVisibility;
```